# Controlling Dynamic Checkbox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

My task is to **read entries from a database** and put a **Checkbox corresponding to each entry**
I have opened a database connection and have created the checkboxes but am **unable to check the setting of the checkbox**. I am storing my **checkboxes using a static array ck[]**

```
int count = 0;
while(dr.Read())  //Reading the Database
{
   CheckBox temp = new CheckBox();  //Creating a temprory checkbox
   temp.Text = dr[1].ToString();    
   temp.Checked = false;  //Making the checkbox intitally empty
   temp.ID = dr[0].ToString();  
   ck[count] = temp;  //inserting the checkbox's references into the array
   ck[count].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(temp_CheckedChanged);  //Adding the even handler
   Panel1.Controls.Add(ck[count]); //Adding the checkbox to panel
   LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl("<br>");
   Panel1.Controls.Add(lc);
   count++;
}
void temp_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //handling the checking and unchecking of the checkbox
{
   CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox)sender;
   ck[index].Checked = !ck[index].Checked;
}
```

The problem arises in the fact that there is no update in the **.Checked** entry of the checkboxes.
I have read many posts here and tried to implement them too but nothing has worked out so far. I have even tried reading the data from the pane on which I am showing it in.

Comment: There is no update in the .Checked entry? not clear

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [checkboxlist](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_checkboxlist.asp). Because you can add items at run time and works like list.

Comment: I read some posts and came to know that it is deprecated. I am thus not using it. Nevertheless, please tell me if it is good and useable?

Comment: In your code I found only one problem. You should create it inside `!Page.IsPostback` and recreate those controls on `PreInit event`. And where you have read it has deprecated.

Comment: I am trying to change the values at the time of button click. I do not think that requires .IsPostBack . Please advice me otherwise